# SWT standalone scrollbar widget

Tags: swt, scrollbar

Is there a way to create a "standalone" scrollbar in SWT? I would like to have a scrollbar which I have full control over myself and use it to control the contents of another widget in a way which isn't possible with the "built-in" scrollbars in the Table widget, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that you probably can't get a scrollbar alone, but I've worked around that with using a Canvas ( or ScrolledComposite ) and then set the content of that composite to exactly the same size as the ScrolledComposite.getClientArea(). That may require a bit fine tuning and you have to make sure that the content component resizes together with the ScrolledComposite, but should be possible.

You can then get the Scrollbars of the ScrolledComposite and use them independently of the ScrolledComposite.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SWT `Slider` widget for this purpose.
SWT Snippet number 17 for code Example: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet17.java

Comment: Better than _derBiggi's_ solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.  If you look at the jni call for the table, you'll see that it's just a flag into the native call.  I'm pretty sure that you can't do what you ask.  You could however use Draw2D to get this done fairly quickly.  Create a `FigueCanvas` with eith an `XYLayout` or a `ColumnLayout` (I think that's what it's called) and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution!

If you use a ScrolledComposite and use the ScrollBars, the setLocation(int,int) function is called of the internal control to adjust it to the scrollbar position.

If you override this function to really set the location to (0,0), the internal control will not be scrolled anymore.

Comment: Can you please provide some code? I do not really understand what I have to do to get a scrollbar on its own. :-(