# Mouse events on an SWT Scrollbar

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar, mouseevent

Using standalone SWT Scrollbars is something of a hack (using [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675514/swt-standalone-scrollbar-widget)), but it can be done. Here's a snippet:

```
ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(
                parent, SWT.V_SCROLL);
ScrollBar scrollbar = scrolledComposite.getVerticalBar();
Shell tip = new Shell(UserInterface.getShell(), SWT.ON_TOP
                | SWT.NO_FOCUS | SWT.TOOL);
// ..stylize and fill the tooltip..
```

Now what I'm trying to do is monitor when the user is interacting with the scrollbar. In particular, I want to know when the user is dragging the scrollbar—and when it has been released—in order to display an Office 2007-style tooltip revealing which page the position of the scrollbar corresponds with.

[image: Word-style scrolling tooltip]

Presently, I have the following code which displays the tooltip:

```
scrollbar.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent event) {}
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
        tip.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It would seem logical then to have the tooltip disappear when the mouse button is released:

```
scrollbar.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        tip.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

However, neither `scrollbar` nor `scrolledComposite` seem to respond to the `SWT.MouseUp` event when the user interacts with the scrollbar.

I presently have a workaround that hides the tip after a timeout, but I'm not satisfied with this. Any insights would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrollbar's javadoc said this:

> When widgetSelected is called, the
>   event object detail field contains one
>   of the following values: SWT.NONE -
>   for the end of a drag. SWT.DRAG.
>   SWT.HOME. SWT.END. SWT.ARROW_DOWN.
>   SWT.ARROW_UP. SWT.PAGE_DOWN.
>   SWT.PAGE_UP. widgetDefaultSelected is
>   not called.

So my suggestion is get your tooltip to appear and disappear is to check for the event.detail type.

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
    tip.setVisible(event.detail != SWT.NONE);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scrollBar.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    }

    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.detail == SWT.NONE) {
            // end of drag
            System.out.println("Drag end");
        }
        else if (e.detail == SWT.DRAG) {
            // drag
            System.out.println("Currently dragging");
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you... But I can see a problem with mousewheel use that throws multiple drag end events...

Answer (score -1):

Paul,

try using addMouseEvent method from a Scrollable object. For example:

```
Scrollable scrollable = scrollbar.getParent();
scrollable.addMouseListener(new MouseListener () {
   void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) { ... }
   void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) { ... }
   void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)  { ... }
});
```

Actually, I don't know if this approach will work. But, it's an attempt.
Good luck!

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. This simply resolves back to the ScrolledComposite, however, which only responds to the events within the composite itself, not in the scrollbars.